# eror in onBindViewHolder when trying to setColor using a variable inside an Adapter

Tags: colors, position

[at com.example.aplikasiku.AdapterProdi.onBindViewHolder(AdapterProdi.kt:24)
at com.example.aplikasiku.AdapterProdi.onBindViewHolder(AdapterProdi.kt:13)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3has.png)

[this is the contents of my adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No87g.png)

I called the color variable in the view holder